Question on using generics to create hash table, unexpected type
Does anyone know how to resolve the following error?
java: unexpected type
  required: class
  found:    type parameter K

It's occurring on this line:
tpl[0] = new K(key);

I'm not sure if I'm using generics correctly here.
class HashT<K, V> {
    int tsize;
    Vector<List<Object[]>> table;
    public HashT(int tsize) {
        tsize = tsize;
        this.table = new Vector<>();
        this.table.setSize(tsize);
    }

    private int hashfn(K x) {
        //return (x.intValue() % this.tsize);
    }

    public void insert(K key, V value) {
        List<Object[]> l = this.table.elementAt(hashfn(key));
        Object[] tpl;
        tpl[0] = new K(key);
        tpl[1] = new V(value);

        l.add(tpl);
    }

    public V get(int key) {
        List<V> l = this.table.elementAt(hashfn(key));
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashT<Integer, String> ht = new HashT<>(10);
    }
}


@daniu, Not really.  It seems like taking this path has issues.  Should I approach this differently?

You can just store the key and value themselves, ie tpl[0] = key; tpl[1] = value;.

Hello! notaorb, Object[] tpl; and tpl[0] = new K(key);, loss tpl = new Object[ 2 ];, and should be tpl[ 0 ] = key;.

you cannot create an instance of a generic type (using a TypeArgument) - there is no type information at runtime   due to type erasure - new K(...) would be compiled, if valid, to new Object(...). Also check the Java Language Specification 15.9. Class Instance Creation Expressions
